# Error installing ionic push plugin (for iOS) on windows

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, cocoapods

I'm developing an app in Ionic for iOS and Android, added both platforms to the project.
I'm getting the following when I add the push plugin. It installs for android, but not for iOS

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --save
> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --save
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
    You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --save (exit code 1):

    Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
    Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
    Error: WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run
    CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

Here is the ionic info

```
PS D:\scripturi\Ionic\dangle> ionic info 
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

Node : v7.2.1
OS   : Windows 10
npm  : 3.10.10
```

Tried removing the platforms and adding them back.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible to develop for mac on windows?

Comment: In theory yes, [https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html) 
"The iOS SDK does not run on Windows, so nothing to do here. Still want to build for iOS, though? Check out Package, part of the Ionic Cloud."

Answer (score 0):

The iOS verison of the plugin requires a [CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/) (Firebase) to be installed. CocoaPods are used to manage ObjC and Swift dependencies and are only available in OSX environments, so it's quite expected that the plugin install fails on windows.

I'd suggest you remove the iOS platfom when developing on a windows machine.